# Get all collection result if null value appears in match filter in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Really don't know how to describe my problem. I tried my best. I have a collection and I want anyone to search through multiple parameters. I used the $match filter for this. here is my code.

```
db.product.aggregate([{$match:{lastStatus:req.query.status,name:req.query.name}}])
```

This is working fine. but I am taking the match values from the user via API and there is a chance that the user didn't pass these values, in that case, I return the products based on the applied match. suppose the user only passes the name, then the result comes on the basis of the name, not on lastStatus. right now this query does not work if any of the provided values is empty or undefined.

what can be the solutions

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition if any of the field has value then set the value in the `match` variable.

```
let match = {};
// MATCH STATUS
if (req.query.status) match["lastStatus"] = req.query.status;
// MATCH NAME
if (req.query.name && req.query.name.trim() != "") match["name"] = req.query.name.trim();

db.product.aggregate([{ $match: match }]);
```